# I'm trying to create a leveling system in QB64 Txt Based Adventure

Tags: levels, qb64

What I want to happen is whenever `expertotal%` is equal to `levelup%`, I want to add `1` to `level%`. I've tried `level% + 1`, but I get a syntax error.

Then whenever `level%` goes up, I want to multiply `levelup%` and `experience%` to be multiplied by `1.25`.

Here is my code:

```
    do

         sub lvl
            level% = 1  
            levelup% = 50  
            experience% = 5 
            ExperTotal% = 0 

        if Expertotal% = levelup% then 'something here to add 1 to level%
while Expertotal% = levelup% 

    ' multiply them both by 1.25

wend
    loop

    end sub
```

Comment: What's wrong with `level% = level% + 1`?

Comment: sorry for the late reply before i put " if expertotal% = levelup% then level% + 1" but a friend told me that i had to put that a line down, thank you for the help though

Comment: No, if the `if` statement is written on a single line you may use the same line for the instructions that complete the statement. The issue is due to the fact that `level% + 1` does mean nothing as BASIC instruction. To increment `level%` you have to use `level% = level% + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting your code somewhat I have come to this:

```
REM What I want to happen is whenever expertotal% is equal to levelup%,
REM I want to add 1 to level%.
REM   I've tried level% + 1, but I get a syntax error.
REM Then whenever level% goes up,
REM I want to multiply levelup% and experience% to be multiplied by 1.25.
level% = 1
levelup% = 50
experience% = 48
ExperTotal% = 48
DO
    COLOR 15
    PRINT "Increase exp(y/n)";: INPUT x$
    IF LCASE$(x$) = "y" THEN
        GOSUB lvl
        COLOR 14
        PRINT "level="; level%
        PRINT "experience="; experience%
    ELSE
        EXIT DO
    END IF
LOOP
COLOR 7
END
lvl:
' increase experience total
ExperTotal% = ExperTotal% + 1
' compare experience to levelup
IF ExperTotal% = levelup% THEN
    ' add 1 to level when experience equal
    level% = level% + 1%
    ' multiply levelup and experience
    levelup% = levelup% * 1.25
    experience% = experience% * 1.25
    COLOR 12
    PRINT "level increased.."
END IF
RETURN
END
```

Comment: Although since you are multiplying by 1.25 you may want to change some of the variables to single precision..

Comment: so this will be a more percise way of leveling? what  i currently have  is      `SUB`
 
` SUB lvl

    level% = 1
     levelup% = 50
     experience% = 5
  `  experiencetotal% = 0

    IF experiencetotal% = levelup% THEN
       level% = level% + 1




    ` END IF


 END SUB`

Comment: I merely adjusted the variables for more simple testing; you can restore them to the original values.